# Comparing arrays and giving out numbers depending on what value is in what array

Tags: php, arrays, compare

This is more a kind of logical Question. Sometimes i think my Brain is not for programming ;(

What i want to do is.

IF array1 and array2 have the same values setup a new array with keyname to the value that the both array have in common and value = 3 OK i already got that.

Now i want:

IF a value is ONLY in array1 set new array value = 1

IF a value is ONLY in array2 set new array value = 2

```
$beidesgeht = array_intersect($acc_conf, $ano_conf);

foreach ( $beidesgeht as $be ) {
    $fertig[ $be ] = 3;
}
```

I guess thats a easy one for you pros. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*After* what you've got up there:

```
foreach ($acc_conf as $el) {
    if (!isSet($fertig[$el])) {
        $fertig[$el] = 1;
    }
}

foreach ($ano_conf as $el) {
    if (!isSet($fertig[$el])) {
        $fertig[$el] = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was ending up with undefined indexes, when i use !isset instead of !defined its seems to be working. thx.